# Filtering models Django

Tags: python, django

I have these models in my models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    main_category= models.ForeignKey(HovedKategori, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class UnderCategori(models.Model):
    main_kategory= models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    supplier = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    info= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link= models.CharField(max_length=200)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.supplier ) + " " + str(self.title)
```

Ho do i query all the different category suppliers without repeating them? What i mean is if i have 10 different suppliers with 500 products combined how do i query the 10 different suppliers. Also im not sure if this is the correct data stucture i should use, if there are any tips on that, that would also be appretiated.

Comment: So do you only want to query suppliers? Without products?

Comment: Yes, i want to query all the different suppliers to the products. Ive been thinking i might want to move the supplier field to the category model. I think that would solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest splitting the supplier from the category like so:

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    main_category = models.ForeignKey(HovedKategori, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class UnderCategori(models.Model):
    main_kategory= models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    info= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link= models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.supplier ) + " " + str(self.title)
```

Then you could simply do `Supplier.objects.all()`
Please note that I don't really understand why there are two different categories. Perhaps one is a sub-category? Also, you are talking about products, not categories. I don't see any 'products' mentioned in your code